# error resolving WCF service using WCF facility

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I keep getting the following error:

```
Method not found: 'Void Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException..ctor
```

this is from the following initialization code in global.asax:

```
    private void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();

        _container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(_container))
            .AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
            .Register(Component.For<ISonatribeCommandService>()
                          .AsWcfClient(DefaultClientModel
                          .On(WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("commandServiceClient")))
                          .LifestyleTransient())
            .Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "Sonatribe*.dll")));

    }
```

my system.servicemodel section in web.config looks like:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://****.com/SonatribeCommandService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CommandService.ISonatribeCommandService" name="commandServiceClient"></endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The service works fine when using the add web reference method.

UPDATE:

I also tried doing the config method too:

```
<configuration>
  <components>
    <component 
      id="commandService" 
      type="CommandService.SonatribeCommandService, CommandService"
      wcfEndpointConfiguration="commandServiceClient" />
  </components>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using incompatible versions of Windsor and the facility. Make sure you're using version of WCF Facility that was meant to be used with the version of Windsor you have.

Comment: That doesn't make it any less likely, especially if you used nuget UI. Make sure they both have the same version.

Comment: sorry, deleted, re-got and then rebuilt

Comment: gah: <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.0.0.3001" />
  <package id="Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility" version="3.0.0.2001" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.0.0.3001" />

Comment: i'm just going to go back to running my own builds... thanks for helping

Comment: Why use your own builds rather than official ones? Just upgrade the WCF Facility to RC1, right?

Comment: that's what i was using - i'm up and running now using my own build from github.

Comment: Right. Why? Are you saying the RC1 of WCF Facility (3.0.0.3001) together with the same version of Windsor and Core were giving you that issue?

Comment: Odd, I'm using it on my project with no issue. Do you think you could get me a test that reproduces that?

Comment: All i'm doing is using nuget to install the wcf facility rc and it pulls in different versions of the dlls as is defined in the xml snippet from the packages.config above.

Comment: i don't suppose you know what is going on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215275/wcffacility-sequence-contains-no-elements as well do you?