# WcfFacility Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I keep getting a Sequence contains no elements error when trying to install my wcf services.

here is the code in my global.asax:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer();

_container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(_container))
          .AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
          .Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig())
          .Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "Web*.dll")));
```

here is my system.servicemodel section in web.config:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://commandservice.website.com/WebsiteCommandService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CommandService.IWebsiteCommandService" name="commandServiceClient"></endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And here is my castle config (within the web.config):

```xml
<castle>
    <components>
      <component
          id="commandService"
          type="CommandService.WebsiteCommandService, CommandService"
          wcfEndpointConfiguration="commandServiceClient" />
    </components>
</castle>
```

Am I missing something obvious?

UPDATE:

here is the stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +371
   Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientExtension.ObtainServiceContract(ComponentModel model, IWcfClientModel clientModel) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a19756d977ce9d2c\src\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration\Client\WcfClientExtension.cs:239
   Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientExtension.ResolveClientModel(ComponentModel model) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a19756d977ce9d2c\src\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration\Client\WcfClientExtension.cs:234
   Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientExtension.Kernel_ComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a19756d977ce9d2c\src\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration\Client\WcfClientExtension.cs:189
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentModelDelegate.Invoke(ComponentModel model) +0
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddCustomComponent(ComponentModel model, Boolean isMetaHandler) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:281
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:536
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:482
   Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUpComponents(IConfiguration[] configurations, IWindsorContainer container, IConversionManager converter) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\Installer\DefaultComponentInstaller.cs:211
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:317
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:453
   Website.MvcApplication.ConfigureContainer() in C:\Users\Wayne Douglas\Dev\ProjectWebsite\Website\Global.asax.cs:65
   Website.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users\Wayne Douglas\Dev\ProjectWebsite\Website\Global.asax.cs:53

[HttpException (0x80004005): Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +4052053
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375

[HttpException (0x80004005): Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11686928
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4863749
```

UPDATE

the problem seems to be somewhere else now - it's like it's trying to resolve the component as if it were a normal object not a wcf service. baring in mind the service works - when trying to resolve it using the wcf i get an error on the ctor:

```
    public WebSiteCommandService(ICommandService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
```

It says that there is no component for ICommandService

why is the client container trying to resolve that?

it's like the wcffacility stuff is being skipped completely?

Here is the stack:

```
[InstanceNotFoundInEnvironmentConfigurationException: Could not find requested type Ncqrs.Commanding.ServiceModel.ICommandService in the NcqrsEnvironment configuration. Make sure that the NcqrsEnvironment is configured correctly or that defaults are correctly set.]
   Ncqrs.NcqrsEnvironment.Get() in C:\Users\Wayne Douglas\Dev\ProjectWebsite\ThirdParty\NCQRS\src\Ncqrs\NcqrsEnvironment.cs:96
   CommandService.WebsiteCommandService..cctor() in C:\Users\Wayne Douglas\Dev\ProjectWebsite\CommandService\WebsiteCommandService.svc.cs:17

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CommandService.WebsiteCommandService' threw an exception.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.nativeGetUninitializedObject(RuntimeType type) +0
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:151

[ComponentActivatorException: ComponentActivator: could not instantiate CommandService.WebsiteCommandService]
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:163
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:116
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:66
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\AbstractComponentActivator.cs:80
   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\AbstractLifestyleManager.cs:81
   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\SingletonLifestyleManager.cs:63
   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Handlers\DefaultHandler.cs:124
   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Handlers\DefaultHandler.cs:98
   Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Resolvers\DefaultDependencyResolver.cs:308
   Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Resolvers\DefaultDependencyResolver.cs:158
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:292
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:85
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:66
   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\AbstractComponentActivator.cs:80
   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\AbstractLifestyleManager.cs:81
   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\AbstractLifestyleManager.cs:70
   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Handlers\DefaultHandler.cs:124
   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Handlers\DefaultHandler.cs:98
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:777
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) in d:\BuildAgent\work\60b7fa65294e7792\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel_Resolve.cs:225
   Website.WindsorControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in C:\Users\Wayne Douglas\Dev\ProjectWebsite\Website\WindsorControllerFactory.cs:24
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +93
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +71
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +161
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +405
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: updated the post to show stack trace

Comment: it's like it's not picking up the config and is complaining about an empty array of services to configure? maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think your system.servicemodel element in your web.config is not quite right.  If you are hosting the service from your web application you would not have a client element in there - instead of the client element I think you should have a services element that looks like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="CommandService.WebsiteCommandService">
    <endpoint address="http://commandservice.website.com/WebsiteCommandService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              name="commandService"
              contract="CommandService.IWebsiteCommandService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: makes sense! i was thinking that it was because I was configuring the client to use the service... thank you.

Comment: i'm not so sure it is that to be honest

Comment: I just had another look - the type in your castle config is "CommandService.WebsiteCommandService, CommandService" but you have FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "Web*.dll")) in your global asax - won't that mean that it only looks in assemblies statring Web and since your service is inside an assembly called CommandService it won't find it?

Comment: the components for the wcf stuff are in the app.config and they are pulled in with  .Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig())

Comment: i've updated this with some more info - this was so much easier last time i tried :(

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working!!

the type in the component config needed to be the interface - the service. I left out the service attribute and it fired into action!

And the system.servicemodel worked with client config.

Don't know if this is a bug?

Comment: Interesting. I guess there should be something - either accepting this behaviour or throwing an exception happening. Can you report this to http://issues.castleproject.org along with a test that reproduces the behaviour (or in this case lack of thereof)